# Infinite series of the form $x^{a(b^n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do you evaluate this series?  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{a(b^n)}$, where $0<x<1$ and $a,b>1$.

For context: This is a model I'm building of family growth. $x$ is the probability that someone has no children, $a$ is the number of children you choose to have, and $b$ is the average number of children your descendants have. So, this is the total probability your family line will ever end.

Comment: @MarkViola Sorry, I meant "evaluate". This is a model I'm building of family growth. x is the probability that someone has 0 children, a is the number of children you choose to have, and b is the average number of children your descendants have. So, this is the total probability your family line will ever end.

Comment: I doubt that there is a useful closed-form solution.  Inasmuch as the series converges, you can apply a host of numerical techniques to approximate the value of the series.  (+1) for the question.